# I need help parsing valid JSON text from a google doc into a JSON object within google appscript

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I'm using google appscript for a project, I'm saving valid JSON text in a google document than using app script i try to get the text from the doc and parse it to a JSON object.

Ive tried many different thing but cannot figure it out anyway below is my code error and logger results.

when i try the below code:

```
function getText() {
  var id = "1hUEzxS4SircCwBEFLCdjblSxLsc0JnhYBSZnXkaAezA"
  var content = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText();
  var data = content.toString();
  var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

I get this error from app script:
'SyntaxError: Unexpected token in object literal (line 41, file "constructor")'

i realize the 'content.toString();' was redundant but i've tried many solutions

when i get rid of the JSON.parse function line and just log data as below:

```
function getText() {
  var id = "1hUEzxS4SircCwBEFLCdjblSxLsc0JnhYBSZnXkaAezA"
  var content = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText();
  var data = content.toString();
  Logger.log(data);
```

the logs return:

```
[19-11-09 11:59:55:134 CST] {  “dateArray” :
 [ "01-02-19" ,  "01-03-19" ,  "01-04-19" ,  "01-07-19" ,  "01-08-19" ,  "01-09-19" ,  "01-10-19" ,  "01-11-19" ,  "01-14-19" ,  "01-15-19" ,  "01-16-19" ,  "01-17-19" ,  "01-18-19" ,  "01-22-19" ,  "01-23-19" ,  "01-24-19" ,  "01-25-19" ,  "01-28-19" ,  "01-29-19" ,  "01-30-19" ,  "01-31-19" ,  "02-01-19" ,  "02-04-19" ,  "02-05-19" ,  "02-06-19" ,  "02-07-19" ,  "02-08-19" ,  "02-11-19" ,  "02-12-19" ,  "02-13-19" ,  "02-14-19" ,  "02-15-19" ,  "02-19-19" ,  "02-20-19" ,  "02-21-19" ,  "02-22-19" ,  "02-25-19" ,  "02-26-19" ,  "02-27-19" ,  "02-28-19" ,  "03-01-19" ,  "03-04-19" ,  "03-05-19" ,  "03-06-19" ,  "03-07-19" ,  "03-08-19" ,  "03-11-19" ,  "03-12-19" ,  "03-13-19" ,  "03-14-19" ,  "03-15-19" ,  "03-18-19" ,  "03-19-19" ,  "03-20-19" ,  "03-21-19" ,  "03-22-19" ,  "03-25-19" ,  "03-26-19" ,  "03-27-19" ,  "03-28-19" ,  "03-29-19" ,  "04-01-19" ,  "04-02-19" ,  "04-03-19" ,  "04-04-19" ,  "04-05-19" ,  "04-08-19" ,  "04-09-19" ,  "04-10-19" ,  "04-11-19" ,  "04-12-19" ,  "04-15-19" ,  "04-16-19" ,  "04-17-19" ,  "04-18-19" ,  "04-22-19" ,  "04-23-19" ,  "04-24-19" ,  "04-25-19" ,  "04-26-19" ,  "04-29-19" ,  "04-30-19" ,  "05-01-19" ,  "05-02-19" ,  "05-03-19" ,  "05-06-19" ,  "05-07-19" ,  "05-08-19" ,  "05-09-19" ,  "05-10-19" ,  "05-13-19" ,  "05-14-19" ,  "05-15-19" ,  "05-16-19" ,  "05-17-19" ,  "05-20-19" ,  "05-21-19" ,  "05-22-19" ,  "05-23-19" ,  "05-24-19" ,  "05-28-19" ,  "05-29-19" ,  "05-30-19" ,  "05-31-19" ,  "06-03-19" ,  "06-04-19" ,  "06-05-19" ,  "06-06-19" ,  "06-07-19" ,  "06-10-19" ,  "06-11-19" ,  "06-12-19" ,  "06-13-19" ,  "06-14-19" ,  "06-17-19" ,  "06-18-19" ,  "06-19-19" ,  "06-20-19" ,  "06-21-19" ,  "06-24-19" ,  "06-25-19" ,  "06-26-19" ,  "06-27-19" ,  "06-28-19" ,  "07-01-19" ,  "07-02-19" ,  "07-03-19" ,  "07-05-19" ,  "07-08-19" ,  "07-09-19" ,  "07-10-19" ,  "07-11-19" ,  "07-12-19" ,  "07-15-19" ,  "07-16-19" ,  "07-17-19" ,  "07-18-19" ,  "07-19-19" ,  "07-22-19" ,  "07-23-19" ,  "07-24-19" ,  "07-25-19" ,  "07-26-19" ,  "07-29-19" ,  "07-30-19" ,  "07-31-19" ,  "08-01-19" ,  "08-02-19" ,  "08-05-19" ,  "08-06-19" ,  "08-07-19" ,  "08-08-19" ,  "08-09-19" ,  "08-12-19" ,  "08-13-19" ,  "08-14-19" ,  "08-15-19" ,  "08-16-19" ,  "08-19-19" ,  "08-20-19" ,  "08-21-19" ,  "08-22-19" ,  "08-23-19" ,  "08-26-19" ,  "08-27-19" ,  "08-28-19" ,  "08-29-19" ,  "08-30-19" ,  "09-03-19" ,  "09-04-19" ,  "09-05-19" ,  "09-06-19" ,  "09-09-19" ,  "09-10-19" ,  "09-11-19" ,  "09-12-19" ,  "09-13-19" ,  "09-16-19" ,  "09-17-19" ,  "09-18-19" ,  "09-19-19" ,  "09-20-19" ,  "09-23-19" ,  "09-24-19" ,  "09-25-19" ,  "09-26-19" ,  "09-27-19" ,  "09-30-19" ,  "10-01-19" ,  "10-02-19" ,  "10-03-19" ,  "10-04-19" ,  "10-07-19" ,  "10-08-19" ,  "10-09-19" ,  "10-10-19" ,  "10-11-19" ,  "10-14-19" ,  "10-15-19" ,  "10-16-19" ,  "10-17-19" ,  "10-18-19" ,  "10-21-19" ,  "10-22-19" ,  "10-23-19" ,  "10-24-19" ,  "10-25-19" ,  "10-28-19" ,  "10-29-19" ,  "10-30-19" ,  "10-31-19" ,  "11-01-19" ,  "11-04-19" ,  "11-05-19" ,  "11-06-19" ,  "11-07-19" ,  "11-08-19" ,  "11-11-19" ,  "11-12-19" ,  "11-13-19" ,  "11-14-19" ,  "11-15-19" ,  "11-18-19" ,  "11-19-19" ,  "11-20-19" ,  "11-21-19" ,  "11-22-19" ,  "11-25-19" ,  "11-26-19" ,  "11-27-19" ,  "11-29-19" ,  "12-02-19" ,  "12-03-19" ,  "12-04-19" ,  "12-05-19" ,  "12-06-19" ,  "12-09-19" ,  "12-10-19" ,  "12-11-19" ,  "12-12-19" ,  "12-13-19" ,  "12-16-19" ,  "12-17-19" ,  "12-18-19" ,  "12-19-19" ,  "12-20-19" ,  "12-23-19" ,  "12-24-19" ,  "12-26-19" ,  "12-27-19" ,  "12-30-19" ,  "12-31-19" ]
}
```

which seems like valid json to me and im struggling to convert the array to a json object.

Answer (score 1):

oops turns out it wasnt valid json wrong backticks
“dateArray” needed to be "dateArray"